# Set custom node color using Python Graphviz package

Tags: python, colors, graphviz

The [graphviz](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) Python package allows setting the color of a node to be a string argument.

```py
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('example_graph')
g.node('Test Node', color='green')
```

I would like to specify a color that uses a precise numerical encoding such as RGB or hexcodes. If I try the following

```py
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('example_graph')
g.node('Test Node', color=(50, 50, 50))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Similarly I tried setting the tuple to be a string:

```py
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('example_graph')
g.node('Test Node', color='(50, 50, 50)')
```

which resulted in this warning and the diagram seems to default to black.

```
Warning: (50, 50, 50) is not a known color.
```

It isn't clear to me what possible arguments are allowed, and [searching the documents for 'color'](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=color) did not reveal any examples other than simple named colors.

Is this possible with the graphviz Python package, or can it only take a small selection of named colors?

Comment: A wild guess: Did you try `color='#505050'`

Comment: @albert Your wild guess works. I'll accept it as an answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a [Github issue](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/issues/142) with the package maintainers. They were kind enough to add a [`colors.py` example](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#colors-py) to their documentation.

One approach from their examples using RGB is the following.

```py
import graphviz

g = graphviz.Graph('colors')

g.node('RGB: #40e0d0', style='filled', fillcolor='#40e0d0')

g.view()
```